# Accessing datasets in HDF5 files containing unusual datatypes

Tags: python, matlab, hdf5, h5py, pytables

I want to analyse some datasets in a .h5 file I have been given using something like Pandas however I have encountered an issue that appears to be a result of some datatypes in the datasets not being supported by the tools I've used so far. I've done a little reading around but I don't understand the tools and problem well enough to troubleshoot effectively and am seeking guidance on the matter.

I can access the datasets using `HDFView` however using this to export all the data to text files and then reading those text files into something else isn't ideal and furthermore doesn't always print out the data in a format I know how to use (i.e. booleans print out as something like `B@38b27cdc` with every such expression appearing to be unique).
I have tried some attempts at accessing the file using python (h5py and PyTables) and MATLAB. Some code examples and outputs are given below.

h5py example using numpy

```py
f = h5py.File('filename.h5', 'r')
group = f["Run 1"]
dataset = group["datasetIAmInterestedIn"]
```

Error output end summary. Let me know if you want to see the full output here.

```py
TypeError: No NumPy equivalent for TypeBitfieldID exists
```

PyTable example

```py
f = tab.File('filename.h5', 'r')
group = f.get_node("/Run 1")
group.datasetIAmInterestedIn
```

Output from command

```
/Run 1/datasetIAmInterestedIn(UnImplemented(58023,)) ''
NOTE: The UnImplemented object represents a PyTables unimplemented dataset present in the 'filename.h5' HDF5 file.  If you want to see this kind of HDF5 dataset implemented in PyTables, please contact the developers.
```

(I've included this in case it is helpful)

MATLAB

```matlab
data = hdf5read("filename.h5","/Run 1/datasetIAmInterestedIn")
```

Output from command

```matlab
Error using hdf5readc
Call to HDF5 library failed (unsupportedDatatype): "Datatype of an attribute value is not supported. Please disable the
reading of attribute values by setting the 'ReadAttributes' argument
to false. Type HELP HDF5INFO for more information.".

Error in hdf5read (line 100)
[data, attributes] = hdf5readc(settings.filename, ...
```

My attempts in exploring usage of `ReadAttributes` have not yielded any useful information or results.

Comment: Python h5py does not support Booleans/Bitfields (see https://github.com/HDFGroup/h5serv/issues/1, https://github.com/h5py/h5py/issues/109). MATLAB does support them in HDF5 but your error mentions attributes, not datasets which seems odd, given how you describe the problem. The only other thing I wonder is if the space in the dataset name is causing a problem?
However without an HDF5 file and actual code it will be hard to debug.

Comment: I confess that my ignorance is probably being a bit misleading here. I've established that the datatypes for each dataset in the group is defined by a metadata group(? it looks that way) and that the datatypes are "Compound". Does that change things? I'm a bit loath to share the dataset as, while it doesn't contain anything sensitive, the company I'm doing this for might take a dim view regardless and I'd rather not risk that.

Comment: If it's compound, then you'll need to build the compound data-type before you can read it (at least in MATLAB, I assume it's the same in Python but I haven't tried). I'll see if I can post some code...

Comment: by the way, in the interest of sharing knowledge: as of version 2.10 h5py can handle bitfields. Just came across this http://docs.h5py.org/en/latest/whatsnew/2.10.html and figured I should share it

Comment: Good to know about bitfields, looks like I'm a couple of years behind the times!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a compound data-type you'll need to define the compound before you can read it.
For example (and here the code is in MATLAB) you have a compound datatype that stores logging entries with strings (of different sizes), a double-precision float that stores a datetime and an integer ID:

```
char32_type = H5T.copy('H5T_FORTRAN_S1');
H5T.set_size(char32_type, 32);
char32_size = H5T.get_size(char32_type);

char64_type = H5T.copy('H5T_FORTRAN_S1');
H5T.set_size(char64_type, 64);
char64_size = H5T.get_size(char64_type);

int_type = H5T.copy('H5T_NATIVE_INT');
int_size = H5T.get_size(int_type);

dbl_type = H5T.copy('H5T_NATIVE_DOUBLE');
dbl_size = H5T.get_size(dbl_type);

sizes = [
    char32_size
    dbl_size
    char64_size
    int_size
    ];

offset = [ 0 ; cumsum(sizes) ]; % zero-based

log_type = H5T.create('H5T_COMPOUND', sum(sizes));
H5T.insert(log_type, 'user',        offset(1), char32_type);
H5T.insert(log_type, 'datetime',    offset(2), dbl_type);
H5T.insert(log_type, 'action',      offset(3), char64_type);
H5T.insert(log_type, 'id',          offset(4), int_type);
```

You can use this compound type `log_type` to read/write the data. E.g. for reading a dataset `/log` in the HDF5 file then something like the following:

```
plist     = 'H5P_DEFAULT';
fid       = H5F.open(log_file ,'H5F_ACC_RDONLY', plist);
log_dset  = H5D.open(fid, '/log');
mem_space = 'H5S_ALL';
log = H5D.read(log_dset, log_type, mem_space, 'H5S_ALL', 'H5P_DEFAULT');


% Close the dataset and file once you're done
H5D.close(log_dset);
H5F.close(fid);
```

The output of the read (`log`) will be a struct. The strings will be char arrays in inconvenient column-format, so will need to be transposed. Here I convert them to cell-arrays but you might want the String class or otherwise. I convert the datetime to an array of dates in string format. The `id` field is fine, and doesn't need fettling.

```
log.user    = cellstr(log.user');
log.action  = cellstr(log.action');
log.datestr = cellstr(datestr(log.datetime));
% log.id is okay as is
```

If you don't know the format of the compound type, then you could be in trouble?

Comment: I think I see. Let me just check my understanding here. In one of the datasets I have the following Dataset Members in the Compound: 3 64-bit floating-points, 2 8-bit bitfields, 2 arrays of 64-bit floating-points, 2 32-bit ints and a variable length String. If I create a unique id in a manner like you have for every individual float, int, array, etc, and assign them to an object to call during the read function as you have, MATLAB should be able to read that particular dataset?

Comment: You don't need a unique ID (I just happened to want to store an int I called `id` in my use case). You need to define the compound-type once (i.e. build your own version of `log_type` out of 10 floats, ints, etc), and then use your version of `log_type` for reading the data. The `log_type` just tells HDF5 the format of the compound data, so you only need one of them and can reuse it for reading/writing.

Comment: Ah ok, many thanks. Last question: does the id of what I insert into my `log_type` need to match the id of the Compound Dataset Members? i.e. one of the array id's is `Data Value->Data Value->Ray->Direction [X;Y;Z](m)` . Will I need to match each such id in the compound-type constructed?

Comment: I don't understand your question! There is nothing special about `id`, it's just a field name. I could rename it to `foo`. The `log_type` just defines the type (int, float,etc) and order of fields in the compound-type. It knows nothing about IDs or indices or anything, it just says "the bytes in the file relates to these fields in this order".The `log_type` does not store any data, it just defines the data layout.

Comment: Sorry, what I mean is the Compound Dataset Members in the .h5 file are all already named. I was wondering if I have to match those names in the `log-type` I make.

Comment: I don't believe so, but might be confusing if you didn't!